# How to add automatically an element to one list (or vector) whenever it's added to another in JAVA

Tags: java, list, vector

let's say I have two Lists(or Vectors),I want one to include all the other's elements of the other, even if the second can get more elements later, they must be added to the first automatically. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("1","2"),l2 =Arrays.asList("3","4");
"missing treatement"
System.out.println(l2);
System.out.println(l1);
```

Displays:

`[3 4]`

`[1 2 3 4]`

if I add to `l2`

```
list2.add("5); 
System.out.println(l2);
System.out.println(l1);
```

I get:

`[3 4 5]`

`[1 2 3 4 5]`

`l1` can contain not only it's own elements and `l2`'s elements but I can have `l3` and `l4` as well ... and any time I modify(add or remove) element from 
`li i>1`

the same happens to `l1`

Comment: make a copy of the list maybe? kinda like a pointer to the memory address holding list 1 so list 2 always contains the same information as list 1 and vice versa since they are the same memory address.

Comment: you can use the below code to copy elements from one to another. Below is just a example. you need to write code which actually copies over the entries to other arraylist .ArrayList<String> src = new ArrayList<String>();
src.add("test string1");
src.add("test string2");
ArrayList<String> dest= new ArrayList<String>();
dest.addAll(src);

Comment: @LearningPhase this might be better suited for an answer, too messy in comments.

Comment: make a custom add method to do this

Comment: did not want to add as an answer as it was just giving an idea instead of the actual solution.

Comment: @jgr208 and want them to to have the same elements that would be so easy, I know how to deal with pointers but what I really want is that one includes the elements(or copies of them cause I want each to be in separate memory space)

Comment: @BenfaresMohamed in that case use `System.arraycopy( src, 0, dest, 0, src.length );` as part of a function

Comment: @LearningPhase  and if I add elements to src later are they going to be added to dest also?

Answer (score 3):

What you want indirectly exists in Java, but is located in the JavaFX side of things. Specifically, you are wanting to use the [**FXCollections**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) which are observable

Using the [**FXCollections.observableList(List<E> list)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) method should return an observable wrapper of the list you passed to the function.

Now do this for both of your lists

Then to make one observe the other, you may have to switch to another part of the JavaFX world which is bindings, i.e. you can use the following method to bind both lists to each other:

[**Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(ObservableList<E> list1, ObservableList<E> list2)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContentBidirectional-javafx.collections.ObservableList-javafx.collections.ObservableList-)

Here you pass to it both of your observable lists, and now you have a binding between both. So when one is updated, the other is updated as well and vice versa

Example program displaying this (*Note I didn't use* `Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(ObservableList<E> list1, ObservableList<E> list2)` *because it binds eagerly and has the potential of emptying both lists if care is not taken*):

```
package com.example;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param observed The list you wish to observe
     * @param <T> Any type
     * @return A pair of lists. The first one is the observer list and second is the observed list
     */
    public static <T> Pair<List<T>, List<T>> observe(List<T> observed) {
        ObservableList<T> fxObserved = FXCollections.observableArrayList(observed);
        ListProperty<T> observerProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(fxObserved);
        return new Pair<>(observerProperty, fxObserved);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> observed = IntStream.range(1, 11).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> observer = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Before binding:");

        System.out.println(String.format("Observed list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observed.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

        System.out.println(String.format("Observer list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observer.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

        // make the list observable
        Pair<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> observingList = observe(observed);
        observer = observingList.getKey();
        observed = observingList.getValue();

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter binding:");

        System.out.println(String.format("Observed list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observed.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

        System.out.println(String.format("Observer list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observer.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

        observer.add(34);
        observed.add(45);

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter adding 34 and 45 to the lists:");
        System.out.println(String.format("Observed list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observed.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

        System.out.println(String.format("Observer list contains: %s", String.join(", ", observer.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Before binding:
Observed list contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Observer list contains: 


After binding:
Observed list contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Observer list contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10


After adding 34 and 45 to the lists:
Observed list contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 34, 45
Observer list contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 34, 45
```

Comment: yes, but how to deal with unidirectional binding with this way

Comment: @BenfaresMohamed what do you mean? Examples?

Comment: in your exemple when you add 45 to observed it would be added to observer but when you add 34 to observer no thing happens to observed

Comment: @BenfaresMohamed, take a look at the output, both lists contain the same thing which implies that when I added 34 to observer, it was added to observed. Maybe I don't understand your question, in that case, you should ask a new question on SO to get better clarification

Answer (score 1):

Make a reference to the address of the arraylist as so

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> second = first;
```

By assigning `second = first`, there is only one arraylist with two references. The references are the same. So, when you make a call with `first` or `second` the call will be performed on the referenced arraylist.

Such as

```
second.add("a");
System.out.println(first.size());
System.out.println(second.size());
```

Will display `1` and

```
first.clear();
System.out.println(second.size());
System.out.println(first.size());
```

Will display `0` since you have cleared the arraylist.

If wanting to use different memory addresses you can then do as such,

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();;
```

and when adding have functions that do the following.

```
public void addFirst(String data){
     first.add(data);
     System.arraycopy( first, 0, second, 0, first.length );
}

public void addSecond(String data){
     second.add(data);
     System.arraycopy( second, 0, first, 0, second.length );
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing `ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
second = first;` instead of `ArrayList<String> second = first;`?  You're just allocating and then immediately discarding an `ArrayList` as it stands.

Comment: @LouisWasserman my mistake made the fix yea i was creating an object for no reason that waste resources.

Comment: @BenfaresMohamed then please explain clearly what you want also "no im not talking about that" does't explain anything you want. You are being unclear so please rephrase the question you are asking to clearly say what you expect and maybe include what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Agh, I was working on an answer similar to jgr208, and came to find that he beat me to it.  It's called using a alias.  I'm not sure there is a clear cut way to do exactly what you are asking without creating some kind of wrapper class or custom collection class.

I would add that it's tough for me to think of a situation (although I'm sure one might exist) where you would want to have two copies of the same data that you have to keep in sync.  As in jgr208's answer, it's better to have the data stored in one place, with two references to that data.  This is more efficient and less likely to create bugs.  Here is my code:

```
    List<String> list1, list2;
    Vector<String> vector1, vector2;

    list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    vector1 = new Vector<String>();

    list1.add("First one");
    list1.add("Second one");

    vector1.add("First one");
    vector1.add("2nd one");

    list2 = list1;

    list2.add("Which list will this be in??");

    vector2 = vector1;

    vector2.add("Oh my goodness!");

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(vector1);
    System.out.println(vector2);
```

Result is:

```
     [First one, Second one, Which list will this be in??]
     [First one, Second one, Which list will this be in??]
     [First one, 2nd one, Oh my goodness!]
     [First one, 2nd one, Oh my goodness!]
```

Comment: I'm not talking about simple pointers manipulation, what 'm talking about is more like unidirectional binding, or adding a listener to list1, so whenever I add to list2, list1 is added to also, but when I add to list1, no thing happens to list2.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  Could I suggest adding a clarification to your question?